# Confirm dialog for all http call react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, modal-dialog

i should develop a confirm dialog callable from all components through react/redux. I have to pass inside redux state 2 callbacks with accept and reject derived from confirm dialog but function are not serializable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass actions instead that are to be dispatched in success / error case.
Redux loop uses this approach as well, for a more generic handling of async effects in reducers (without violating the purity of reducer):
https://redux-loop.js.org/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#write-a-reducer-with-some-cmd-objects-side-effects

Comment: Where could I put logic (http call) after confirm click(action dispatched)?

Comment: That depends where you handle async logic in general.
We use `redux-saga`, but the mentioned `redux-loop` would also be an option.

Comment: The puristic redux approach would be a middleware.
The mentioned libraries are implemented as middlewares / store enhancer, with abstractions to simplify usage.

Comment: last question: now I know which is the correct action to call but, how I bind this action with the correlate function in middleware ?

Comment: If you want to do 'vanilla' middleware, you provide a function with the signature `store => next => action =>`. It gets called with every action and has to check if it should handle the action.
See here: https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware#the-final-approach